# Как получить общее значение выпитых литров. Команда /leaders

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3, telegram

Хочу создать команду /leaders, что-то наподобие как на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В db.py у меня есть данная функция не знаю как назвать, а именно **get_totalenergetik**: #UPD

```
import sqlite3
import time

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
            
    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
            self.connection.commit() ###

    def add_energetik(self, number, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `number` = `number` + ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (number, user_id,))
                self.connection.commit() ###

    def get_totalenergetik(self, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `number` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?;", (user_id, )).fetchall() ### UPD

    def get_top_rows():
        connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        with connection:
            return cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users order by number limit 0,5").fetchall()
```

И вот команда: #UPD

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['leaders'], chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def leaders(message: types.Message):
        answer = ''
        data = db.get_top_rows()
        i = 0
        for x in data:
            i += 1
            name = await bot.get_chat(x[1])
            answer += f"{i}.{name['first_name']} - выпито {x[2]} л. энергетика.\n"
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
```

UPD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в `get_top_rows` в `bd.py` добавьте `self` как аргумент функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция для извлечения топ записей из бд, которая извлечет 5 строк с самыми большими значениями в `numbers`:

```py
def get_top_rows():
    connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    with connection:
        return cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users order by number limit 0,5").fetchall()
```

Хендлер для команды

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['leaders'], chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def leaders(message: types.Message):
    answer = ''
    data = db.get_top_rows()
    data.reverse()
    i = 0
    for x in data:
        i += 1
        name = await bot.get_chat(x[1])
        answer += f"{i}.{name['first_name']} — выпито {x[2]} литров энергетика.\n"
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
```

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Отступы поправьте

Comment: NameError: name 'get_top_rows' is not defined, вроде-бы поправил отсутпы поправил, файл db.py сохранил.

Comment: Если вы импортировали файл, то все должно работать, поправил ответ

Comment: TypeError: get_top_rows() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given, теперь он жалуется на это.

Comment: обновите свой вопрос, покажите какой вид имеют ваши файлы сейчас

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите.

Comment: Добавил картинку результата, что-то не очень правильно показывает оно.

Comment: @Riktik да, ошибся, обновил вопрос, сейчас будет все правильно. Если ответ Вам помог, то пометьте его, как правильный. Если остались вопросы - создайте новый вопрос.

Comment: а вот как-то можно чтобы у 1-2-3 места были медальки ? 

Comment: создать словарь вида `{1:, 2:}` и тд. И в хендлере доставать смайл по значению переменной `i`